# How to make the bottom edge of columns align to the same level?

Tags: css

I have a question about displaying a set of columns so that the bottom of the columns are at the same level.

http://jsfiddle.net/arieanneke/s0g4oese/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

.column {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.column_long {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 210px;
    width: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

So the question is, how can I make the bottom of the blue column at the same level than the red columns?

The problem is that the longblue column is pussing the 3 red columns down.

Kind regards,

Arie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how I'd lay it out (look instead at [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS tables](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) however, what you have can simply be corrected to:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
.column, .column_long {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.column_long {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    height: 214px;
}
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/s0g4oese/6/

**or using css-tables...**

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.row {
    width: 250px;
    display:table-row;   
    height: 100px;
}

.column, .column_long {
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50px;
}

.column_long {
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column_long"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `float:right` to `.column_long`

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
.column {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
.column_long {
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  height: 210px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column_long"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `flex-box`.

Note...I'm cheating by changing the **display order** here.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items:flex-end;
    height: 220px; /* required */
}

.column {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.long {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 210px;
    order:2; /* make this one last */

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column long"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```